# Xcode 5.1 can't connect to my Iphone 5S with Ios 7.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I get the following message:

Xcode cannot run using the selected device.

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Tried connecting to multiple USB ports, deleted xCode with the delete developer tools command in terminal, reinstalled and rebooted.

Please help me out!

Comment: Do you have valid certificate and provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes had no problems with testing on my iphone before

Comment: ohh, Did you set the deployment target to 7.1?

Comment: Wasn't set to 7.1, checked just before your comment, didn't work though. Thanks for the quick replies btw

Comment: Is your device running the min. iOS version required by your deployment target?

Comment: Deployment target is minimum required version of iOS to run on. Check Architectures

Answer (score 0):

Check Architectures Section in Build Settings tab of your Project. iOS 7.1 must be set as Base SDK. If it's not in list, update your xCode to last version. Also try select from list and set again Certificate and Provisioning profile. Sometimes it helps.